# I won't be able to earn Wireless or Field Work hats

Tags: feature-request, winter-bash-2015

Having only Windows Phone as mobile operating system I won't be able to earn any of these two hats: [Wireless](http://winterbash2015.stackexchange.com/wireless) nor [Field Work](http://winterbash2015.stackexchange.com/field-work)

Is it possible to know when will you guys stop undervaluing the Universal Windows Platform and start working on an app for it?

It isn't that hard you know.

Comment: I don't think there was ever a question of difficulty, but rather a question of market share.

Comment: I don't think my last phrase is implying it. If it looks like it I'll remove it.

Comment: Why not use a phone with an operating system that is widely supported?

Comment: @TinyGiant I am using an operating system with a wide support, It is just not as widely supported as the other two.

Comment: Maybe you can install an Android or iOS development emulator and run the SE app inside it.  Or, you know, stop worrying about hats.

Comment: I kinda agree with the OP. I have an android phone but still why divide hats based on OS?. I hope that there isn't a hat like - *upvote 5 times using your Samsung S6 edge phone* :P

Comment: In 6 to 8 weeks...

Comment: @rene Not according to [Geoff Dalgas](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/215992/stack-exchange-android-app-in-beta#comment699299_215992) since Jan 2014

Comment: I got all my Android-only hats last year using an emulator.

Comment: *why divide hats based on OS?* @VinodMadyalkar - Looks like they want to encourage people to use their mobile apps.

Comment: This question doesn't deserve the downvotes. A Stack Exchange app for Windows 10 would not be nonsense at all... and wouldn't harm anyone using other platforms!

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom It is not hats that I worry about, it is the fact that **SE ignores [valid requests from the community](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225624/official-stack-exchange-application-for-windows-phone-os)** that bothers me. The marketshare argument is invalid the moment things like Winterbash and Aprils fools got dedicated resources every year for absolutely **no value other than fun** while truly useful things are left out from SO plans. Anyway, your comment is appreciated since it is the most useful one, specially for others in my situation that **do** care about hats.

Comment: And for the record I am not against hats (neither April fools) since you can see me wearing one... until it evaporates on the end of Jan 3rd

Comment: It is all about market share, really.  Us Windows Phone Bros© have to deal with it, unfortunately.  It's more likely they create a UWP app that works on the desktop (big marketshare) and the phone (small marketshare), but don't expect movement on that anytime soon.

Comment: Building a Windows Mobile app is likely much more expensive than Winter Bash

Comment: There's [an API](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs)... You're obviously a developer, since you *must be* to be able to make a statement like "it's not that hard". [Let us know when you're done](http://stackapps.com/).

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan There are already apps there like [MetroStack](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/apps/metrostack/9wzdncrcwb6r) and [StackCook](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/apps/stackcook/9wzdncrd202n), it is still no valid reason for not existing an official app.

Comment: @CarlosMuñoz that is an amazing Sun Wukung hat though...

Comment: @hellyale I may not get those hats but I got this one instead because of this question

Comment: @CarlosMuñoz see, it all worked out =)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use a friends phone if you have to... it isn't impossible... but since they are imaginary hats that disappear soon, it really doesn't matter **that** much.

Comment: Imaginary hats? So you're saying they don't exist and what I'm seeing on the screen is a figment of my imagination?

Comment: I'm saying they aren't physical

Comment: @hellyale Is the money in your bank account imaginary too?

Comment: @user10014 sure hope it doesn't disappear at the end of the year.

Comment: This is what I did in the end, but still the issue remains, I hope one day Stack Overflow will care enought to make an official app for Windows. By the way I'm keeping my Sun Wukong hat for a while.